# dbus-launch and dbus-daemon - what's happening

Tags: security, ps, d-bus, ipc, processes

I grepped the `ps` output for `dbus` with the following output:

```
102    742   0.0  0.0   4044  1480 ?        Ss   Apr16   27:13 dbus-daemon --system --fork --activation=upstart
xralf  2551  0.0  0.0   4076  212  ?        Ss   Apr16   0:14 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session dwm
xralf  2554  0.0  0.0   3936  224  ?        S    Apr16   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session dwm
xralf  2555  0.0  0.0   4248  1684 ?        Ss   Apr16   0:07 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
root   9970  0.0  0.0   3944  476  pts/5    S    May08   0:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch f6ddc5d5c514b5fb84725db7000007cd --binary-syntax --close-stderr
root   9971  0.0  0.0   3268  308  ?        Ss   May08   0:00 //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
```

Everything was run automatically. Could you explain what is happening
in the system and if it's secure?

Notice especially username `102`, `//bin/dbus-daemon`.

Comment: I don't see how someone can answer your question unless you define what you mean by "is the system secure".  Also, exactly what are you wanting explained w/regards to "what is happening in the system".  Of note, the '102' in the user column indicates a misconfigured system (no user for UID=102, but something is running as UID=102).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide much information about your system though. DBus system usually has two buses: a system bus and a session bus.

- Session bus is started per user (in your case for root and xralf), lines 3 to 6. Line 2 is a dbus service that was requested by your window manager.
- A system bus is needed for system-wide message exchange. This is your first line started under UID 102. The reason for UID to be shown instead user name could be that
  [the user name is longer than 8 characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2386/what-would-cause-ps-to-report-uid-instead-of-username/2401)
  You could check your `/etc/passwd` to look up this UID.

This is how it looks like on my system:

```
message+    924      1  0 13:31 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

and a corresponding `/etc/passwd` entry:

> messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false

dbus-launch is a [utility to start a message bus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html). In more recent distribution this is done by systemd.

Comment: It seems worth stating directly that the mysterious “message+” username is apparently merely a truncated version of the username “messagebus” given the aforementioned eight‐character limitation. (It’d be easier to understand things if the `ps` and `top` commands used the (U+2026) ellipsis character to indicate truncation instead of the plus sign character…)

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -o user:15,pid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd -p 742`
```

If the name is too long for the standard output for username (8 characters), then it shows the UID or same strange acronym. `user:15` tells `ps` to show 15 letters for user name.

Example:

```
$ ps aux | grep exim
Debian-+  1259  0.0  0.0  53244  3192 ?        Ss   10:23   0:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m

$ ps -o user:15,pid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd -p 1259
USER              PID  PPID  C STIME TT           TIME CMD
Debian-exim      1259     1  0 10:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
```