# ps command shows user id and not user name

Tags: centos, users, ps

With Centos 6.6, when I run `ps` command, the first column is User ID and not user name.

```
root@cluster:mahmood# ps aux | grep Xvnc
506      11881  0.6  0.1 168580 63164 ?        S    Jun03  24:56 /usr/bin/Xvnc :6 -desktop cluster.hpc.org:6 (haghsheno) -auth /home/mahmood/.Xauthority -geometry 1000x900 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/mahmood/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5906 -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -pn
```

Why such thing happens? and how can I change that to user name?

Comment: Is answerd hier why https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363910/dbus-launch-and-dbus-daemon-whats-happining/365837#365837

Comment: Does it show the numeric UID for processes of all users, or just some? Do `getent passwd 506` and `getent passwd $username` work? (I think `getent` should lookup by number on CentOS)

Comment: It shows for some users. As pointed by Bahamut, it seems that the user name length is important!

Comment: or maybe you have a numeric username: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/why-cant-linux-usernames-begin-with-numbers/287079#287079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the id is not inside passwd (`grep 506 /etc/passwd`) there is no username to display.

In this case add an corresponding entry inside `/etc/passwd`.

**EDIT**
As mentioned by [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) and [KevinO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108158/kevino):

*This answer isn't quite complete!* It's better to locate these lines from /etc/passwd, whose third field (`$3`, separated by colon `-F:`) contains exactly the value of `506`. *See first comment from Jeff*. My simple example above would show lines containing username yx506, id 123506, and so on.

But anyway: if the userid is missing inside `/etc/passwd`, this answer *could* be a solution.

I'll try to be more concrete in future ...

Comment: or `awk -F: '$3 == 506' /etc/passwd` or `getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 == 506'`

Comment: Yes, my example could result in more than just one line. Wanted to keep it simple ... ;) Thanks anyway!

Comment: This answer isn't quite complete, as an entry may be in `/etc/passwd` but still not display the textual user name. As an example, I have from `ps -ef` a line of :`68   1964  1   0 May17 ? 00:00:30 hald` (so it is showing the numeric id; most other lines have "root" or "apache" showing), but `grep 68 /etc/passwd` gives `haldaemon:x:68:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin`.

Comment: userid 1506, username tax506, gid 5061, etc etc etc

Comment: @Jeff/Kevin: I hope the edit is acceptable for you ...

Comment: The user doesn't have to be listed in `/etc/passwd`, it could be in some other user database such as LDAP.

Comment: By default it is fetched from passwd. There is no hint from OP about custom configuration, so default is to be assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the default ps does not display a username if the username is longer than 8 chars.  If your system is running sssd with LDAP you can use "**getent passwd userid**" to find the user if they are in the LDAP database or the password file. My username "tvb" almost always shows up.  However the username "**flonglastname**" would not in most cases.  Other commands like "**w**" will show the first 8 chars "**flonglas**" and truncate the remaining.  In the example by @KevinO above, "**haldaemon**" is 9 chars so that's why it doesn't appear in ps as a username, but a userid instead.

```
% getent passwd haldaemon
haldaemon:x:68:68:HAL daemon:/:/sbin/nologin
```

Also, the answer at [blog.dbi-services.com](https://blog.dbi-services.com/list-usernames-instead-of-uids-with-the-ps-command-for-long-usernames/) helps with a way to specify the field length of the username field even in BSD format ps output.  Simplifying their suggestion a little gives:

```
env PS_FORMAT='user:12,pid,%cpu,%mem,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,command' ps ax | grep haldaemon
haldaemon     2032  0.0  0.0  53100  2020 ?        Ssl    Aug 12 00:01:10 hald
```

Which provides the desired output.

Comment: You know that you don’t need to use `env` to run a command with a customized environment, right?

Comment: @G-Man: It depends on which shell you're using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946736/.

Comment: Actually by using "env" the command is shell agnostic.